# extending function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to extend my jquery the following way, it isn't working.

```
var y = {
    alertData: function () {
        alert('z');
    },
    hideData: function () {
        $(this).hide();
    }
};
var z = $('#a');
$.Extend(z, y);
z.hideData();
```

Comment: Typo? Its `extend` starting with a lower case  `e`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try extending like this?

```
$.fn.extend({
    alertData: function () {
        alert('z');
        return this;
    },
    hideData: function () {
        this.hide();
        return this;
    }

});
```

And using it like this on an element with `a` as id?

```
$('#a').alertData().hideData();
```

The reason your implementation wasn't working was :

- The typo, its not Extend, its extend
- Its `this`, not `$(this)` inside extend

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/TkA2e/